# Privoxy/VPN/remote proxy

Tags: proxy, vpn, privoxy

On Privoxy, my current config involves this. (forwarding all requests to netshade proxy):

```
forward   /      nl1.netshade.net:350
```

Now, I would like to use a VPN on top of this config while keeping my current forwarding. If my understanding is correct, would I need to amend the "listen-address" or play with "forward-socks"? If so, how to. I don't know how to setup this up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the answer on my own.

Keep your current Privoxy `config` file as is. If you're running Privoxy on the same machine as you browse, there's no need to amend the default `listen-address` section. Also, there's no need to play with `forward-socks`.

To turn on the VPN, you need Rayner Software's [NetShade](https://secure.raynersw.com/netshade.php). Choose, for example, the `nl1.netshade.net` VPN Server. That's it! Do NOT play with the `Proxy Server` section of NetShade so long you wish to control that section through Privoxy `config` file only.

NetShade Proxy Section can be translated into the following in Privoxy `config`:

```bsh
# Begin “forward” Section
#
#        forward   /      nl1.netshade.net:350
#        forward   /      de1.netshade.net:350
#        forward   /      cz2.netshade.net:350
#        forward   /      uk4.netshade.net:350
#        forward   /      uk3.netshade.net:350
#        forward   /      ca1.netshade.net:350
#        forward   /      us6.netshade.net:350
#        forward   /      us4.netshade.net:350

         forward   :443
         forward   localhost
#
# End of “forward” Section
```

Typically, if you choose, for example, `nl1.netshade.net` as VPN in NetShade, you will comment out this line: `forward  /  nl1.netshade.net:350`

However, while keeping the above VPN choice as is in NetShade, you can also choose another proxy by commenting out, for example, `forward  /  ca1.netshade.net:350` in the above configuration. If you do it, NetShade will pop up dialog box telling you there's a discrepancy between IPs (the proxy you choose and the VPN); you can disregard it! Your connexion is still secured via VPN, even if you choose the additional layer of security by choosing another proxy.